# Negation of there exists quantifier?

Tags: predicate-logic

The problem states to find the negation of the following statement:

> There exists a number which is equal to its square.

Original Answer: There does not exist a number which is equal to its square.

My answer: There exists a number which is not equal to its square

Are both the answers above equal? if not then what am I missing? To me both the answers are not equal from a mathematical point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not the same. "There exists a number equal to its square" means the set of such numbers is not empty. The negation of this is that the set of such numbers *is* empty, i.e. there does not exist a number equal to its square.

There exists a number equal to its square (1) and there exists a number not equal to its square (2). Since both these statements are true, they can't be negations of each other. So your answer was not correct.

Comment: Wow Never thought it like this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your answer presupposes the existence of a number. Think of the following example to see the problem.

> *Statement (1)*: There exists a unicorn with a yellow fur.

This statement is false. Yet, so is the statement:

> *Statement (2)*: There exists a unicorn which has no yellow fur.

Indeed, the correct negation of statement (1) is

> *Statement (3)*: There does not exist a unicorn with yellow fur.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... to me most of these questions make sense if I put it is not true that in the beginning itself. But now I get why.

Answer (score 2):

The negation of “For some X, P(X) holds” can be stated in several equivalent ways:

- “For no X, P(X) holds”
- “For all X, P(X) does not hold”
- “For all X, (not P)(X) holds”

Your original answer is the first of these forms and is correct.

Your second answer is incorrect. It is sort of like the third of these forms, but uses “For some X” instead of “For all X”.

Comment: I now find it safer to use Not in front rather than somewhere in the middle. It removes a lot of ambiguity. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(n):n^2=n$.

Then the question is $Q:\exists n \;\;\text{s.t.}\;\; P(n) \;\;\text{is true}$

$Q$ is true, therefore $\lnot Q:\not\exists n \;\; \text{s.t.}\;\; P(n) \;\;\text{is true}$

is false.

Let $Q':\exists n \;\;\text{s.t.}\;\; P(n) \;\;\text{is false}$

and so $Q'$ is true (and $\lnot Q'$ is false).

Therefore $Q'\ne \lnot Q$.

$\lnot Q$ is the negation of the statement (which is what the problem asks for), and $Q'$ is a negation of the predicate.

Comment: got it ... thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

This will be helpful to understand negation:

Statement with universal quantifier: $\forall x, p(x)\implies q(x)$.

It's negation is $\exists x, p(x)\land \lnot q(x)$

Statement with existential quantifier: for some $x, p(x)\land q(x)$.

It's negation is $\forall x, \lnot p(x)\lor \lnot q(x)$ which is further equivalent to
$\forall x, p(x)\implies \lnot q(x)$.

> Your statement is "for some $x$, $ x$ is a number and $x^2=x$."

It's negation will be "$\forall x$, if $x$ is a number then $x^2\ne x$" which when formulated in language gives "***Every number is not the square of itself***."

Comment: HI Nitin, any sources where i can build these basics... I am finding it particularly hard to go through MIT 6.042J without these basics in place. I started out with my school maths to analyze what I missed during my high school. This question is a missed piece.

Comment: @Aura MSE is a great place to learn parallely alomg with the usual textbooks or programme you are indulged in.